# Automatic change geometry of a PointZ

Tags: pyqgis, point, expression

Is there a way to create an action or a process that updates the Z value in the geometry column of a point layer when a point or multiple points are moved or added/created? Currently, I can do this manually with Field calculator by applying:

```
geom_from_wkt (
   'POINT ('
   ||round (x ( @geometry),3)||' '||
   round (y ( @geometry),3)||' '|| 
   round (raster_value ( @dem,1,make_point (x ( @geometry),y ( @geometry))),3)||')'
)
```

expression to the geometry column, where `@dem` variable is set as a layer variable to the point layer and represents the name of a raster layer containing elevation data. Maybe something could be done with `QgsExpressionContext()`, but all I could find is to change/populate a field, not the geometry column.

I presume there should be a PyQGIS workaround to this problem, but my knowledge of PyQGIS isn't up to that level. I am open to anything at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will read the Z value of the underlying raster and update all points Z's.

```
def givelayer(name):
    """A function to return a layer using the layer name as input"""
    return QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(name)[0]

#Change Draped and DEM to the names of your point- and rasterlayers
pointlayer = givelayer("Draped")
demlayer = givelayer("DEM")

with edit(pointlayer):
    for f in pointlayer.getSelectedFeatures(): #For each point feature
        g = f.geometry() #Fetch the geometry
        rastervalue = demlayer.dataProvider().sample(g.asPoint(), 1)[0] #Extract the raster value from the point features location
        p = g.constGet() #Fetch the point object from the geometry
        p.setZ(rastervalue) #Set its Z from the raster value
        f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry(p))
        pointlayer.updateFeature(f)
print("Done")
```

It finishes in <0.01 s for 10 000 points when I test it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Adding it to my plugin as we speak!